# NPM in Visual Studio 2015 just won't install anything

Tags: visual-studio-2015, npm, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I have the latest version of node.js, v6, and the `npm.cmd` in my VS Web Extensions contains this command, as many google hits have said it must:

```
@”C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe” “C:\Program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js” %*
```

Every time I change `package.json` in an 'Empty' Core 1 project, I get the following error in the output window:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>
> ====npm command completed with exit code 1====

Any ideas what could be wrong? Bower installed it's files just nicely, and everything else seems to be working fine. The app builds and runs, I just can't get Angular2 installed, or anything under npm.

Comment: Can you open the command line, and run `npm.cmd` from VS Web Extensions? Like this: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm.cmd"` (including the quotes)? Does it work correctly?

Comment: No, I get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`, but `npm.cmd' is in that path. I'm checking deeper now for an incorrect path or filename. Thanks.

Comment: @qbik Looks like the end-point file, `npm-cli.js`, was corrupt. I took out an errant line, and now npm at least tries to install.

Comment: @ProfK did you resolve this, if so can you provide your solution?  I have same issue `====npm command completed with exit code 1====`

Answer (score 9):

My answer is a bit late, but maybe it helps people with the same problem. I encountered it while trying to get Angular2 up and running.

- In Visual Studio goto Tools>Options
- Open the 'Projects & Solutions' tab and goto 'External Web Tools'
- Add a new entry pointing towards your local node.js installation (or
  install one if you don't have it) eg c:/programms/nodejs/  and move
  it to the top of the list
- Restart Visual Studio and restore packages - it should run
  successfully now.

Visual Studio is shipped with an old version of npm - telling it to use your local nodejs fixes that problem.

Note: Check if npm version is at least 3.x.x

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. Surely will work for you. But this method will only 
  works if you are going to restore package.json file to run AngularJS2.

```
     $ cd project_working_directory
     $ npm init -y # create package.json
     $ npm install  typings --save
     $ npm uninstall typings --save
```